# Closed Port with Transmission

Tags: ufw, transmission

Quite new to ubuntu so still learning.

I'm trying to get transmission working but it shows that 51413 is closed. I'm just looking at the settings in Transmission and under Network > Peer listening port it says Port is closed.

Looked into port forwarding from router but the setting doesn't exist. It has IPv6 enabled so apparently no need for port forwarding. So how do I open the port?

I've not got the ufw enabled but I probably should as a security measure. Any help or links to guides would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How, exactly, are you determining that port 51413 is closed? Please be detailed: Complete input and output helps much more helpful than summaries. You can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1213018/edit) to add as much detail as you need.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/195758/how-do-i-open-port-51413-for-transmission and https://askubuntu.com/questions/460673/firewall-rules-for-transmission

Comment: This is a known bug in transmission. It may show a properly opened port as closed.

Comment: Bug reports for port 51413 are listed https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=port+51413

Comment: Thanks for the help but nothing has actually worked. I've disabled the firewall to rule that out. Transmission is still not connecting to any peers and the port shows 'closed' in preferences.

My hunch is that it's something related to the config.json file but I'm not sure what it could be that I need to change.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I fixed it. After I looked at the message log and it told me there was a UDP error and I needed to add a log to /etc/sysctl.conf. Now I've added those lines it's working.

Testing the port through the Transmission UI still show 'Port closed'. My guess is that because I'm using UPnP it doesn't require port forwarding.

Comment: which lines you added after that it's work

Comment: I had to add "net.core.wmem_max="<number provided in log>